# I updated the program showed this error: android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated the program showed this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null object reference
        at com.shwan.food.zone.adapter.FoodGridAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(FoodGridAdapter.java:89)
        at com.shwan.food.zone.adapter.FoodGridAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(FoodGridAdapter.java:28)
```

FoodGridAdapter

```
package com.shwan.food.zone.adapter;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout;
import com.shwan.food.zone.R;
import com.shwan.food.zone.model.Food;
import com.shwan.food.zone.setting.MyBaseClass;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FoodGridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodGridAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private List<Food> original_items = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Food> filtered_items = new ArrayList<>();
    private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();
    String myFStyle;
    Typeface font1;
    TextView tquote,tquote2,tquote3,duration;
    String myFColor;
    int myFSize;
    private Context ctx;

    // for item click listener
    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, Food obj, int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mOnItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView name;
        public TextView dreja;
        public TextView duration;
        public ImageView image;
        public MaterialRippleLayout lyt_parent;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);

            dreja = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rang);
            duration = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.duration);
            image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
            lyt_parent = (MaterialRippleLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.lyt_parent);

        }
    }

    public Filter getFilter() {
        return mFilter;
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public FoodGridAdapter(Context ctx, List<Food> items) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        original_items = items;
        filtered_items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public FoodGridAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_food, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        myFStyle = MyBaseClass.preferences_base.getString("Font_Style", null);
        font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(v.getContext().getAssets(),  myFStyle);
        vh.name.setTypeface(font1);
        vh.dreja.setTypeface(font1);
        vh.duration.setTypeface(font1);
        myFColor = MyBaseClass.preferences_base.getString("Font_Color", null);
        int i = Color.parseColor(myFColor);


        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
        final Food p = filtered_items.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(p.getName());

        holder.duration.setText(p.getDuration());
        holder.dreja.setText(p.getDreja());
        holder.dreja.setText(Html.fromHtml(p.getDreja()));
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(p.getPhoto()).into(holder.image);
        setAnimation(holder.lyt_parent, position);
        holder.lyt_parent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                    mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(view, p, position);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //Here is the key method to apply the animation
    private int lastPosition = -1;

    private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position) {
        // If the bound view wasn't previously displayed on screen, it's animated
        if (position > lastPosition) {
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, R.anim.slide_in_bottom);
            viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
            lastPosition = position;
        }
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return filtered_items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            String query = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            final List<Food> list = original_items;
            final List<Food> result_list = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                String str_title = list.get(i).getName();
                String str_cat = list.get(i).getCategory().getName();
                if (str_title.toLowerCase().contains(query) || str_cat.toLowerCase().contains(query)) {
                    result_list.add(list.get(i));
                }
            }
            results.values = result_list;
            results.count = result_list.size();
            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filtered_items = (List<Food>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to call `setTypeface` three times - and at least one of them will be on a null object. Find out which one that is.